# What is the best way to get a datetime or date in a urlconf in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

In my URLconf I would like to be able to pass no time at all, a date or a date + time like so:

/posts/

/posts/2010-01-01

/posts/2010-01-01 20:30

In my view I would like to create either a datetime.datetime object or a datetime.date object

What would be the best way of writing this in a urlconf?

Comment: you need regex for date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to also seperate the year/month/day with slashes, so can easier integrate (maybe also later on) views that eg. display a yearly/monthly overview:

```
r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(<?P<hour>\d{2})-(<?P<minute>\d{2})/$
```

Comment: In most cases I would think that his is the way to do it, in my case the user will not be able to get data based on year or year + month only date and date with a specific time but I'l definitly split the date and time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups . Likely you'll need something like :

```
(r'^posts/(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{2})-(?P<day>\d+)/(<?P<hour>\d{2})-(<?P<minute>\d{2})$', 'posts'),
```

Note this is untested, and you'll still have to make this a datetime object in the view, for converting to datetime see http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime